# Angular mat-table removes hardcoded rows

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have some rows that I need to display at the top of the data regardless of the data. However, `mat-table` strips out my rows. It has to be within the same table since it will have a `colspan` that will relate to the data below it.

Can I tell `mat-table` to leave these rows alone?